# Evenly spacing views using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

A common use for [`LinearLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is to evenly space (weight) views, for example:
[image: example layout]

How do you implement evenly spaced views like this using the new `ConstraintLayout`?

`ConstraintLayout` links for reference: [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html), [I/O session video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO9aX87hq9c)

Answer (score 393, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this using `ConstraintLayout`: [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) and [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html). To use Chains, make sure you are using `ConstraintLayout` Beta 3 or newer and if you want to use the visual layout editor in Android Studio, make sure you are using Android Studio 2.3 Beta 1 or newer.

**Method 1 - Using Chains**

Open the layout editor and add your widgets as normal, adding parent constraints as needed. In this case, I have added two buttons with constraints to the bottom of the parent and side of the parent (left side for Save button and right side for Share button):

[image]

Note that in this state, if I flip to landscape view, the views do not fill the parent but are anchored to the corners:

[image]

Highlight both views, either by Ctrl/Cmd clicking or by dragging a box around the views:

[image]

Then right-click on the views and choose "Center Horizontally":

[image]

This sets up a bi-directional connection between the views (which is how a Chain is defined). By default the chain style is "spread", which is applied even when no XML attribute is included. Sticking with this chain style but setting the width of our views to `0dp` lets the views fill the available space, spreading evenly across the parent:

[image]

This is more noticeable in landscape view:

[image]

If you prefer to skip the layout editor, the resulting XML will look like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_save_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_share"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_share"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_share_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_save"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Details:

- setting the width of each item to `0dp` or `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` lets the views fill the parent (optional)
- the views must be linked together bidirectionally (right of save button links to share button, left of share button links to save button), this will happen automatically via the layout editor when choosing "Center Horizontally"
- the first view in the chain can specify the chain style via `layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle`, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) for various chain styles, if the chain style is omitted, the default is "spread"
- the weighting of the chain can be adjusted via `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`
- this example is for a horizontal chain, there are corresponding attributes for vertical chains

**Method 2 - Using a Guideline**

Open your layout in the editor and click the guideline button:

[image]

Then select "Add Vertical Guideline":
[image]

A new guideline will appear, that by default, will likely be anchored to the left in relative values (denoted by left-facing arrow):

[image: layout editor relative guideline]

Click the left-facing arrow to switch it to a percentage value, then drag the guideline to the 50% mark:

[image: layout editor percent guideline]

The guideline can now be used as an anchor for other views. In my example, I attached the right of the save button and the left of the share button to the guideline:

[image: final layout]

If you want the views to fill up the available space then the constraint should be set to "Any Size" (the squiggly lines running horizontally):

[image: any size constraint]

(This is the same as setting the `layout_width` to `0dp`).

A guideline can also be created in XML quite easily rather than using the layout editor:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Comment: I could not find a way how to create a guideline with a constraint. I want a horizontal guideline to be in the middle of two views. Imagine a bigger view with 100dp height on top and smaller one with 50dp height on bottom. I want to place a guideline in the middle of the space between them.

Comment: I don't think you can add constraints to the guideline itself. You could add multiple guidelines and then constrain the views to those guidelines. You may want to post a new question up with details on what you're trying to achieve. Feel free to paste it back here as well.

Comment: I want to give proportional width to views. For eg I want share button to have twice the width of save button. Without using guidelines since my views are not positioned next to each other like in this example. is it possible?

Comment: You have to convert the values given by guidelines into actual margins or paddings. Guidelines work in the design mode only.

Comment: Can we do something like this: If I hide the first button, the second button is automatically aligned to center..?

Comment: Seems like guidelines is the way to go. Simple. What do you guys think, which method works best for you?

Comment: Just to add to the answer for the case of chains, pls make sure to remove all the margins in the direction in which you want to create the chain. For e.g. if you want to create a vertical chain, then ensure that all the concerned views do not have top and bottom margins else the vertical chain option will not even appear.

Comment: I’m trying to achieve the same but with a reusable layout that is included twice in the main layout. Unfortunately it’s not working (layouts are shrinking to zero size) when I use 0dp as width when they should actually match constraints. Please help me

Answer (score 73):

To create 2 views in same line, equal width, just need to define

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note**

- width = 0dp (`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`)
- Constraint of `button1` and `button2` must like above

**Result**
[image]

**MORE**
If you want `View1` bigger than `View2` you can use `weight` or `percent`.
Example, `View1` width = 2 *`View2` width use **weight**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Example, `View1` width = 2 *`View2` width use **percent**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.667"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.333"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 24):

Well if it helps someone

the **key** is here `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` and
the best thing about constraint layout is that it supports circular dependency and here this is what I have done using exactly that.

**For first child**
`app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputSecondChild"`

**For second child**

`app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textInputFirstChild"`

here is the complete demo

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputParent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/state" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputFirstChild"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textInputSecondChild"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputParent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextChildOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/pin_code" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputSecondChild"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textInputFirstChild"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputParent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextChildSecond"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/country" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 16):

You shoul read about weighted chains. An example of code is here.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/figure_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/figure_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/figure_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/figure_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/figure_1"
        tools:text="2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/figure_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/figure_4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/figure_2"
        tools:text="3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/figure_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/figure_3"
        tools:text="4"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, set `android:layout_width="0dp"`, `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"` and link every view with neighbours like:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/figure_2"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/figure_4"
```

[image]

Comment: what the point of posting one more answer exactly like another one, posted two years ago?

Comment: @Subzero, I saw many times equal answers with high rate. Even code lines were the same. I suspect, some authors copied from mine and even got more pluses. In this case answers are different, I also used other sources to understand how weights work in `ConstraintLayout`, and only first answer was not enough to get a picture above.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have your chained items, you can still use weights on them like relative layout to keep them evenly spaced.  The example below shows how to keep them evenly spaced with different size textViews.

```
<TextView1
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" />
 <TextView2
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" />
 <TextView3
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" />
 <TextView4
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1" />
```

[image]