# Android ConstraintLayout : Three buttons equally distribute across the width

Tags: android

I have a `ConstraintLayout` that contains 3 buttons horizontally. I want the 3 buttons to have a fixed width and be evenly distributed across the width of the layout.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here is a visual example.

1. Select the views
2. Right click and choose **Chain > Create Horizontal Chain**

[image]

See also

- [ConstraintLayout: pack vs chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639504/android-studio-layout-editor-constraintlayout-pack-vs-chain)

Comment: This does not work if the buttons are different widths

Comment: Just to add to the answer, pls make sure to remove all the margins in the direction in which you want to create the chain. For e.g. if you want to create a vertical chain, then ensure that all the concerned views do not have top and bottom margins else the vertical chain option will not even appear.

Answer (score 16):

To make 3 view equally distribute across the width just need to set constraint `start/end` of each view must define correct

**Code**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

**MORE**
If you need 3 views full width, just need to change  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to  `android:layout_width="0dp"`

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Does not work if you have more than 3 try it with six icons and the view is large and icons are small.

Comment: if i need all button of different width then?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_inference"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    app:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp">


    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button7" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this one is the real answer from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works for me...

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_save_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button_share"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_share"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_share_text"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_save"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please refer this link to know more about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518745/evenly-spacing-views-using-constraintlayout

Answer (score 1):

You can use guideline with the percentage tag please check below xml and  replace with image or button anything you want

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMyProperty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin12"
    android:visibility="visible"
   >
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"
        android:id="@+id/Guideline1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"
        android:id="@+id/Guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myPropertyImage1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/homeImageH"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/Guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Guideline1"
        tools:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myPropertyImage2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/homeImageH"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/Guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myPropertyImage3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/homeImageH"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What if i need all button of different width then?

Answer (score 1):

Just set android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="0dp" in all the 3 buttons

Answer (score -2):

try to use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="92dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="92dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="92dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i know the solution using linear layout. Can you help me using constraint layout ??