# How to create a 6x3 grid layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a basic table with 6 rows and 3 columns. The rows represent the days and columns represent morning/evening. The layout I desire to create:

[image]

I want to be able to color the nodes (red and green for availability). Also each row is stanched on the whole width of the screen. I have created something similar with `TableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/shifts_table"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_sunday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sunday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_sunday"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_morning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_morning"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_sunday_morning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_morning"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_sunday_evening"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_sunday_evening"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_sunday_evening"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_evening"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_monday"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_monday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_monday" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_monday_morning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_morning"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_monday_morning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_morning"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_monday_evening"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_monday_evening"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_monday_evening"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_evening"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_tuesday"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_tuesday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_tuesday"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_tuesday_morning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_tuesday_morning"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_tuesday_morning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_morning"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_tuesday_evening"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_tuesday_evening"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_tuesday_evening"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_evening"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_wednesday"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_wednesday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_wednesday"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_wednesday_morning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_wednesday_morning"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_wednesday_morning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_morning"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_wednesday_evening"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_wednesday_evening"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_wednesday_evening"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_evening" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/table_row_thursday"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_thursday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/form_thursday"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_thursday_morning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_thursday_morning"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_thursday_morning"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_morning"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_thursday_evening"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_thursday_evening"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_thursday_evening"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/form_evening" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I have checkboxes (instead of nodes to fill). I tried to convert the `TableLayout` to `GridLayout` (without checkboxes) but it looks like not a trivial mission. From this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016343/gridlayout-not-gridview-how-to-stretch-all-children-evenly) I learn it is not easy to starch the rows. What would be the easiest way of creating such table with `Grid` with API 16?

Comment: ConstraintLayout would work just fine for that.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, how would you use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846261/trying-to-replicate-gridlayout-column-alignment-with-constraintlayout

Comment: Oh you mean to use `ConstraintLayout` instead of  `GridLayout`? If so, isn't it possile to do it with `GridLayout`, I prefer that way.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/morning"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/evening"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="5"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="5"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_item_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_item_margin"
            android:background="@color/grid_items_background_color"
            android:text=""
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_row="5"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]