# Using ConstraintLayout, can I get the vertical constraint to match the dynamic width of a chain?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-2.3

I have a grid of four buttons in my layout. I have chained them horizontally, so that the space to the left, right, and between the buttons is evenly weighted.

[screenshot of my app's buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khpwj.png)

Can I make the two rows of buttons have the same amount of space vertically between them so it doesn't look uneven? I would rather not just center them vertically like I did to achieve the horizontal spacing, which done thanks to @AdamK of this post: [Evenly spacing views using ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518745/evenly-spacing-views-using-constraintlayout)

activity_main.xml:

> ```
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.jason.notifier.MainActivity"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView3"
>         android:layout_width="388dp"
>         android:layout_height="164dp"
>         app:srcCompat="@drawable/banner"
>         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/testbutton"
>         android:layout_width="171dp"
>         android:layout_height="136dp"
>         android:onClick="sampleNotification"
>         android:text="Test"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/settingsbutton"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/historybutton" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/settingsbutton"
>         android:layout_width="171dp"
>         android:layout_height="136dp"
>         android:text="Settings"
>         android:onClick="settingsbutton"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/testbutton"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pingbutton" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/pingbutton"
>         android:layout_width="171dp"
>         android:layout_height="136dp"
>         android:onClick="pingbutton"
>         android:text="ping"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-31dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/historybutton" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/historybutton"
>         android:layout_width="171dp"
>         android:layout_height="136dp"
>         android:onClick="historybutton"
>         android:text="History"
>         android:layout_marginTop="-31dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/pingbutton"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_width="358dp"
>         android:layout_height="42dp"
>         android:text="TextView"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />
>
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

Comment: Share your constraint layout XML

Answer (score 0):

Place a `View` widget in the center of your layout with a dimension ratio of 1:1 and constrained on the left by `historybutton` and on the right by `pingbutton`. This will give you a square where each side is the length of the horizontal gap.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/spacerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pingbutton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/historybutton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/historybutton" />
```

Now constrain the bottom two buttons to the bottom of your square as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/testbutton"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="136dp"
    android:text="Test"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spacerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/historybutton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/settingsbutton"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="136dp"
    android:text="Settings"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spacerView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pingbutton" />
```

And that should do it. I made the square view visible so we could see it, but you should make it invisible. Here is an image of the effect.

[image]