# How to draw 3 button with equal vertical distance between them in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to have equal vertical distance between each button from top to bottom irrespective of screen size. Here is the code for same :

- Design should work on all types of screen sizes.
- No static values to be used.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:weightSum="3"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

[image]

Comment: what the problem with this layout ?

Comment: @FaizMir As you can see in layout image they are not equidistant from each other

Comment: but the image you posted in that the button have same equidistance

Comment: @FaizMir No, distance between top of the screen and button1 is not same as distance between button1 and button2 and same applies with button3

Comment: @AmanSaxena - have you tried ConstraintLayout ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518745/evenly-spacing-views-using-constraintlayout

Comment: That would make the button1 look smaller because you have navigation bar

Comment: @AmanSaxena check this https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb

Comment: Can you post a pic as to how exactly you want?

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki yes but with constraints layout static values in dp will be added and code becomes somewhat hardcoded

Comment: @AmanSaxena - Maybe data binding will solve that for you? So that you can calculate the dimensions inside `ViewModel` and pass them to your view? I'm shooting blindly here :) sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

One potential way is to use a `ConstraintLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. This will allow you to chain these 3 buttons together which would cause them to be equidistant.

See [this article](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) for more details on how to create chains of widgets

Answer (score 0):

Easy and you do not need to use constraint layout. Just change button1's parent LinearLayout height to `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ConstrainLayout is the best solution in this case. But if you still want to use linearLayout than you can try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="7"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 3" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```